# Can not import package org.springframework.messaging and use MessageHandler interface

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, spring-messaging

I have spend quite some time trying to figure out how do I import and use 
`MessageHandler` interface from `spring framework`.
So here is what I do with my IntelliJ Idea IDE:

> import org.springframework.messaging;
>
> @EnableWs @Configuration public class WebServiceConfig extends
>   WsConfigurerAdapter implements MessageHandler { ...

Furthermore, I have tried to setup my build.gradle script, in order to teach my IDE to use spring-messaging as follows:

```
compile("org.springframework.spring-messaging:spring-boot-starter-web-services")
```

or according to [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-messaging/4.0.0.RELEASE):

```
compile("org.springframework.spring-messaging:4.0.0.RELEASE")
```

None of my desperate attempts was successful..
I can't even see relevant library among my External Libraries listed.
Can anybody tell me what am I screwing up ?

Many thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither dependency coordinates you use properly.

Let's go to the Maven Search and copy & paste it from there!

```
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services'
```

https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.springframework.boot%7Cspring-boot-starter-web-services%7C1.5.6.RELEASE%7Cjar

```
compile 'org.springframework:spring-messaging:4.3.10.RELEASE'
```

https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.springframework%7Cspring-messaging%7C4.3.10.RELEASE%7Cjar

Now you have to reimport the Gradle project to your IDE to make it understand what you provide with the dependency management.

Comment: Thanx for hint. This did help like a snap !